# Comma usage in a letter opening

Tags: commas, formality, salutations

My colleague and I disagree on how to open a letter; he believes you should separate the salutation from the name, like so:

"Hi, John"

I think this is nonsense and that the comma should go at the end, like so:

"Hi John,"

Is there a formal definition/right answer?

Comment: If you're going to use *Hi* you've already dispensed with formality!

Comment: That's a good point!

Comment: And I certainly would NOT start a letter - as distinct from an e-mail - in that manner. But, NO I would not put in a comma. If you came up to John and said "Hi John" to him, would you pause between the two words? If not, it doesn't require a comma.

Comment: You mean I may no longer start a letter or email with "Hi, John:"?

Comment: The "proper way" to write it is "Hi, John. How are you?" if everything is on the same line, and "Hi, John, //[NEW LINE]// How are you?" if the salutation is on one line and the body of the message begins on the next line. Calling something "nonsense" is merely an expression of a personal opinion, just as is calling something "proper" or "correct", unless you're bound by law or custom to follow certain rules. In the military, there are correct & incorrect ways of composing documents like letters. In the law courts as well. For emails & personal letters, there are none. Clarity is all here.

Comment: @rhetorician No-one said *you may not* start a letter that way. I said that *I* certainly wouldn't start a *letter* that way (because I consider it too informal for a letter). I also said *as distinct from an e-mail*, clearly implying that I *may* start an e-mail that way.

Comment: @TrevorD:  Gotcha.  What about the comma I inserted after "Hi" and the colon after "John"?  Are they OK in an email?  Just wondering!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have never come across the *"[salutation], [name],"* format and it looks very strange to me. Certainly it is not the *normal* way to start a letter or email. *"[salutation] [name],"* is more normal. (I do not believe the former is correct, but cannot cite any sources to back me up at present)

Generally, a comma should only be used where you would pause if speaking (or reading the letter aloud). Since you would not normally pause between the salutation and the name, a comma should only be used to artificially introduce a pause there. Thus a comma is not normally used.

The comma at the end of the line is a different matter. It does not follow normal rules of grammar (in any other sentence or paragraph a full stop/period would be used) and is used only by tradition. For what it's worth, this varies in other languages; Spanish, for example, ends the first line of a letter with a colon, as in *"[salutaion] [name]:"*.